# Can`t access config panel after the installation of Ubercart and e-commerce modules

Tags: ubercart

Fatal error: Call to undefined function dpm() in /home/u275855040/public_html/sites/all/modules/ecommerce/ec_store/ec_store.tokens.inc on line 10 How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You are using dpm function to print variable. To fix this issue you just need to enable the devel module or comment the dpm function.

Comment: ...or remove the line altogether